# YQL query on an ajax dynamically loaded html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yql

I want to scrape a page using YQL but the page is loaded via ajax using json files and the returned data is the html file with out any data. It there a way to make sure the page is fully loaded before returning the data via YQL? Thanks in advance! Ryan

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, jquery ajax success function will return the fully loaded response. I use it quite often and I have never had it return a partial response from an ajax request where I would be required to wait for more data.

Have you used the Firebug NET tab to verify what is being sent and received back in your ajax requests? If not, thats a good place to start to see whats going on.

Comment: But if I do this...

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A//inetspace.com/labs/json.html%22

I don't get the table the way its rendered.

Any ideas on how to wait for the table to be rendered?